# How can I include a URL with its own parameters in a query string?

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to post a YouTube URL along with some other data. The YT URL has 2 parameters and looks something like this:

```
http://youtube.com/embed/ytid?wmode=transparent&showinfo=0
```

The full URL would be like this:

```
http://mysite/proc.php?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=(the youtube url)
```

Without the second param (showinfo) it works correctly. But having an ampersand as part of of a parameter value splits the parameter itself, so my query string parameters end up looking like this:

```
param1: val1
param2: val2
param3: http://youtube.com/embed/ytid?wmode=transparent
showinfo: 0
```

How should I be handling this?

[EDIT] As helion3 pointed out, the query string needs to be html encoded and it is. The encoded value looks like this:

```
http://youtube.com/embed/ytid?wmode=transparent&amp;showinfo=0
```

And the query string parameter ends up like this:

```
param3: http://youtube.com/embed/ytid?wmode=transparent
amp;showinfo: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to encode the data for inclusion in a URL.

You tagged this as php, which has [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode):

`urlencode('the&info')`

Comment: The query is being encoded so the param value becomes &amp;showinfo=0,  but it still breaks as it's still using an ampersand. I'm going to edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: That's not from urlencode... that's from `htmlentities`. Using `urlencode` would produce `the%26info`

Comment: What helion3 said. urlencode doesn't transform code into html entitys, it uses the hex representative.

Comment: That is it! Thank you, helion3! I knew I'd handled this before.